# Password Generator to Output to a File

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a big project for school where I would get an input of an integer and with that int I would use random chars to output the requested length. I have a problem where I would create a file called "output.txt" with "a" for append the results in to the file called output.txt. What I want is after the result is stored into the file I want it to be displayed.

```
    print(password_generator(user_input_converted), file=file)
```

Comment: Have the `password_generator` function return what you want displayed, then this will work as you put it.

Answer (score 2):

Just call print twice. Once with `file` and once without.

```
password = password_generator(user_input_converted) 
print(password, file=file)
print(password)
```

Assuming `password_generator` is returning the password - which your code seems to imply.

Comment: that worked! for some reason when I tried that it was giving me the file type and other params to the file like utf=8. But thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use open() as here:

```
passFile = open(file, 'a')
password = password_generator(user_input_converted)
passFile.write(password + '\n')
passFile.close()
print('The password is:', password)
```